# Style a single button in antdesign

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I am new to ant design 5 and I've gone through the docs and I can't seem to find a way to style a single button component without affecting other buttons.

What I want is to change the hover background color of only the following link button:

```
<Button type={"link"} href={link} >{cta}</Button>
```

without affecting other link buttons. How can that be achieved?

Comment: One way to achieve this is by using a custom class for your button and applying styles to that class.

Comment: You can use classNames prop to style different parts.

Answer (score 1):

This can simply be achieved by using inline CSS or creating a custom CSS class for the specific button.

```js
import { Button } from 'antd';

//...rest of code

  const customStyle = {
    transition: 'all 0.3s',
  };

  const customHoverStyle = {
    backgroundColor: 'lightblue',
  };
// Or you can also take it to external css file

  return (
    <Button
      type="link"
      href={link}
      style={customStyle}
      /*...other props*/
     >
      {cta}
    </Button>
  );
}
```

***[SAMPLE DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/icy-tree-2nhzhg?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js)***

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [nested ConfigProvider](https://ant.design/docs/react/customize-theme#nested-theme):

```
<ConfigProvider
  theme={{
    token: {
      colorPrimary: '#f00',
    },
  }}
>
  <Space>
    <Button type="primary">Default theme</Button>
    <ConfigProvider
      theme={{
        token: {
          colorPrimary: '#0f0',
        },
      }}
    >
      <Button type="primary">Nested theme</Button>
    </ConfigProvider>
  </Space>
</ConfigProvider>
```

Or use Button `style` prop passing inline styles:

```
<Button
  type="primary"
  style={{
     backgroundColor: '#f00',
  }}
>
  Custom button
</Button>
```

Or use `className` prop and style it using a `css` file:

```
<Button
  type="primary"
  className="custom-button"
>
  Custom button
</Button>

// css file
.custom-button {
  background-color: #f00;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting global CSS. In this case, it's '.ant-btn-link'. Antd allows [Customize Theme](https://ant.design/docs/react/customize-theme), but to target a specific and unique object, I think replace will be effective.

Answer (score 0):

Heres an example of overriding the CSS of a standard AntD component: a Button.

```
    import styled from 'styled-components';
    import { Button } from 'antd';

    const StyledButton = styled(Button)`
      color: red;
      width: 400px;
    `

    const YourRegularComponent = () => {

        return (
            <>
                <StyledButton>
                    This is going to be a button with red text and pixel width 400!
                </StyledButton>
            </>
        )
    }

    export default YourRegularComponent
```